# self-referential generic types in flowtype

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I'm trying to build a better Flowtype definition for Koa library and am kinda stuck.

My idea was to use Generic types to be able to specify customized Context class to Koa, so we can actually typecheck additional fields (populated by middlewares) instead of treating them as `any`.

so, I have:

```
declare type Context {…}

declare class Application<T: Context<T>> extends events$EventEmitter {
    context: T,
    …
}
```

fine…

but Context has a back-reference to Application, which is a generic dependent on Context. How do I spell this in typelib?

This doesn't look right, as I actually want to use not original `Context` but the type which was actually used by user

```
declare type Context {
    app: Application<Context>
}
```

Comment: Actual issue https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/3212